# Using StatET with Eclipse in Win64: "no session of R is active in the current workbench window"

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

What do I do when I get the following error message in Eclipse when trying to launch R?

"no session of R is active in the current workbench window"

Comment: Sounds like you didn't start and R session.  You need to set up and activate a Run Configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a tutorial for installing StatET on my Win64 system, you can find it [here](http://gforge.se/2012/05/setting-up-statet-eclipse-in-windows/)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170722203553/http://gforge.se/2012/05/setting-up-statet-eclipse-in-windows/)). Although it's no rocket science it's easy to get into issues along the way.

You need to first configure R for your system and then you also need to go into *Run > Run Configurations...* and add a R Console before you can run it.

You also need to be careful about the Java version that you use. I had to uninstall all my Java, then reinstall the 64-bit before it worked. I guess I could've used the 32-bit, but since I use 64-bit R I thought that it might be a better option (although I think the Eclipse environment and R don't really care about sharing bits)

Answer (score 2):

for me had to select rterm, that displayed the r console/terminal. Then do run , run as -> run  in R as script via source

Answer (score 1):

I had the sampe problem. 
go to Run > Run Configurations > RStudio

and klick on "Run"